# Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : error in statement: near "[

Tags: sqldf

I need to to know why the mention error appear although when i replace DFinal[i,"x"] with any numeric value it works fine. Appreciate your help

```
for( i in 1:nrow(DFinal)){
+     result =0
+     var1= DFinal[i,"x"]
+     var2= DFinal[i,"y"]
+     result <- sqldf(' select count(distinct(V5)) from DLoc where V1= DFinal[i,"x"] and V5 in (select distinct(V5) from DLoc where V1=var2) ')
+     
+     DFinal[i,"res"]<- result
+     
+ }
```

Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: near "[i,"x"]": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make any sense, because you are referring to R variables.  Instead, use the variables' *values*:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DFinal)) {
    result <- 0
    var1  <- DFinal[i, "x"]
    var2  <- DFinal[i, "y"]
    query <- paste0('select count(distinct V5) from DLoc where V1 = ', var1,
                    ' and V5 in (select distinct V5 from DLoc where V1 = ', var2, ')')
    result <- sqldf(query)

    DFinal[i, "res"] <- result   
}
```

Your query looks like it might also need some improvement, but the above code should at least allow you to run it.

Another comment: It is generally not advisable to concatenate together a raw SQL query because it opens the possibility for a SQL injection attack.  But as you are running this query in a presumably closed R environment, it might be OK as is.